# Autocomplete is not working properly while entering special characters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

The special characters which I entered, do not match with the auto completed results.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: I got a feeling that it shows the tags in the order of their usage amount when no matches are found.

Comment: @Script47 yes! I agree with you.  But it's showing empty values when I entered too `spaces` or  unmatched characters like `fgdfgdfgdfgdfg`, etc `, At this time it does not shows the tags in the order of their usage amount. :(

Comment: I can understand why an empty input might not work (trimmed input?) however the gibberish I'm not too sure about.

Comment: +1 for trying to helpfully identify a bug. -1 to people that downvote because it just so happens this is by design -- it could easily be a bug elsewhere, and I can understand why this is confusing behavior, which is always valuable feedback

Answer (score 5):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

That's working as intended.

When you enter only those special characters, the system shows you a list of all tags, sorted by usage, as fallback.